# If $f$ is continuous at $b$ and $f(b)=a$ and $\lim _{y\to a} g(y) = L$, then $\lim_{ x\to b} g(f(x))=L$.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Problem: If $f$ is continuous at $b$ and $f(b)=a$ and $\lim _{y\to a} g(y) = L$, then $\lim_{ x\to b} g(f(x))=L$.

My attempt:

Let $f(x)=0$, $g(x)=x^2/x$, $a=0$.

$f(0)=0$

$\lim _{y\to 0} g(y) = L$

$\lim _{x\to 0} g(f(x))=g(\lim _{x\to 0} f(x))=g(0)= \text{undefined}$

Therefore statement is false.

I'm not convinced that my answer is correct, because I'm unsure about $g(\lim _{x\to 0} f(x))=g(0)$.

Comment: What are the assumtions on $g$ and $L$ in the original problem? Is $a=0$ in your example? What is $L$ in your example?

Comment: @Gary Right, I missed that part. f, g: R->R. a, b, and L belongs to real

Comment: I guess an even simpler counterexample is $f(x)=a$ (for all $x$) and $g$ not continuous at $a$ (either from a jump discontinuity or because it is undefined there). Then $g(f(x))=g(a)$ for all $x$, which may not equal $\lim_{y \to a} g(y)$.

Comment: $g(f(x))$, in your example, is undefined for all $x$ -- no need to even pass the limit through $g$.

Comment: In your example, $L$ is not real. So your $g$ does not satisfy the assumption of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If $g(y)$ is continuos then $g(f(x))$ is continuous because the composition of two continuous functions is continuous. So as long as all the 'regularity' conditions for the limit to exist hold, then $\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x))=g(\lim_{x\to b}f(x))=\lim_{y\to a}(g(y))=L$.

However, if $g$ is not continuous then you can find a counterexample where $g$ has a discontinuity that will not allow you to interchange limit with function.